# Which Ubuntu for Eee 901 - to run from SD card?

Tags: lubuntu, gui, eeepc

I would like to use linux on our company laptop Asus Eee 901 - specs:

*CPU Intel Atom 1.66 GHz, 
RAM 1 GB DDR2
Display 8.9 inch, 1024x600 pixels*

As I am not allowed to modify the OS and MBR I want to boot from SD slot and use some SDHC card (can buy something like Class 10 for better performance).

I need some user friendly distro with GUI. In first approach the laptop will serve as portable device for sorting and backup photos (to external usb HDD) and videos on holiday and occasional web access.

So I need some usable image viewer, file manager and current web browser - capable to run on the screen only 600 pixels high... And running a little bit more quickly than the Windows :-)

What would you recommend? Lubuntu?

thanks

Comment: Lubuntu, since it has low amounts of RAM. My Asus 1201n eeepc has 4 GB of RAM so I can run Ubuntu 13.10 on it :).

Comment: I am only afraid of the resolution. I often face problem where the app window or settings etc. is unable to fit to the screen and sometimes there is almost no way to move the window to access the buttons...

Comment: well try the Live-USB/CD to see for yourself.

Comment: @Juhele You can press *Alt* and drag inside window to move it. This might only work on default Ubuntu (with Unity) though.

Comment: @minerz029 thanks, works for Lubuntu as well :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lubuntu is great, WattOS uses about 75MB of ram when completely installed. Installing it uses about 90MB of ram. It's based off Ubuntu too so it's very familiar and fast.